# BLDC motor poles versus Torque and RPM

Tags: motor, speed, torque, rpm

How to calculate the cost of a BLDC motor? Assume I need 24 stator coils of height 10 mm and width 5 mm. Is there any formula for torque comparison with increasing the number of poles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formula to calculate the cost of a motor from the number of coils and width and height. Each motor is priced differently you will just have to search around online and see if you can find a motor that meets your speed, torque and size requirement.